# Blender 2.9 - how to delete animation action?

Tags: animation

I got animation action I want to get rid of, how to do it?

Tried to do simple thing as clicking "X" in action editor but it doesn't work.

[image]

I tried do it through *Outliner* window, I found an action, right-click on it, "Delete" and whole rig got deleted.

[image]

I am obviously not following Blender UX mindset, I got like couple of dozens cloned actions already, littering whole scene (was experimenting...) I can't sleep knowing they are sitting there.

Comment: In the Outliner, right click on the "Animation strip". (1st under the 'Fpp_Hands_Rig' strip)  Select "Clear animation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete them the way you're trying to, maybe it moves your object as it is not transformed by the action anymore:

[image]

You can also go in the *Outliner*, choose *Display Mode > Blender File* and under *Actions*, delete the actions you want with a left click > *Delete*:

[image]

Also, if you press Shift and the X button on the right of the action name in the *Dope Sheet*, it will be marked as 0 (no user), it won't be saved when you'll close your file and in the *Outliner > Display Mode > Orphan Data* it will be displayed as orphan and you can delete it immediately if you want:

[image]

[image]